# CSS: Sticky Footer using Flexbox – avoiding the vh unit by setting percentages?

Tags: css, flexbox, sticky-footer, viewport-units

I am experimenting with using Flexbox to implement a sticky footer (footer is at the bottom of the page, even when there is little content).

I found a great example of this on the [web](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/):

HTML:

```
<body class="Site">
    <header>...</header>
    <main class="Site-content">...</main>
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.Site {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mr5scpxz/)

Note: Won't work in all browsers because of unprefixed declarations, maybe try it in Chrome

While this works I don't like the use of the `vh` unit because that unit is even less suported than Flexbox. So I tried to use percentages instead of `vh`:

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1m1pwy1/1/)

(To keep it short I only post the code that changed, but a full example is in the Fiddle.)

Now the solution is not working anymore because the `body`'s parent – the `html` element – has no height declared, so `min-height` has no reference. So I've tried to set

```
html,
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

but that also [did nothing](http://jsfiddle.net/yoocfb3u/1/). Probably because that way, also the `html` element has no reference. As a conclusion, I have to do it like this to get it working again:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsohr5ue/1/)

While this seems to work, I am not sure of the side effects of using `height: 100%` on the `html` element. I remember some years back, I once rendered a website unusable by using something similar without the matching overflow declaration.

*Are there any downsides of this solution? Are there maybe more robust solutions using percentages?*

Comment: That's a very long question to ask if 100% height on the html screws up stuff, in my experience no, it does not. The scrolling still works and so forth. I would say that what you had in the past was 100% and a position:absolute without the overflow, that would not be a good plan. ;-)

Comment: If the browser supports newer flexbox specification, then, in all likelihood, it will also support viewport units.  Also, there are non-flexbox implementations of sticky footer that will work in older browsers.  I think you should just use one of those.